# Earth Engine App: How to load a layer from select dropdown?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to create a dropdown menu and when the user selects an item I want it to load that layer. This is my code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/dfbb128862bd8a3b0fb2139f5b0f5a28

```
var layers = {
    SRTM: ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4"),
    Slope: ee.Terrain.slope(ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4")),
}

  function changeLayers(x) {
  Map.layers().reset(layers[x.getValue()])
}


var s = ui.Select({
  placeholder:'Select Layer', 
  onChange: changeLayers})
Map.add(s)
```

What should I provide in the `items` menu so that it loads the layer from the dictionary. It expects an array though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to use the same keys in the layers object as labels, you can use

```
items: ['SRTM', 'Slope']
```

To control the label, you can do this:

```
items: [
  {value: 'SRTM', label: 'Some label for SRTM'}, 
  {value: 'Slope', label: 'The Slope label'}
]
```

Altogether, might look like this:

```
// Define Layers as a dictionary
var layers = {
  SRTM: ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4"),
  Slope: ee.Terrain.slope(ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4")),
}

//create a function
function changeLayers(layerKey) {
  Map.layers().reset([layers[layerKey]])
}

// Make a selection ui.element that will update the layer
var s = ui.Select({
  placeholder: 'Select Layer',
  items: [
    {value: 'SRTM', label: 'Some label for SRTM'}, 
    {value: 'Slope', label: 'The Slope label'}
  ],
  onChange: changeLayers
})
Map.add(s)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6199bcb31b98b53b14ab822f137d06c6

Comment: Thank you Daniel, You helped me with previous code as well, I was not able to understand the logic. Really means a lot :)

Comment: Respected Sir, I have posted another question, I was wondering whether you will help me with this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455728/google-earth-engine-adding-two-select-boxes-to-a-panel